# How can one create a design style?

Tags: style-identification, style

How can a person create a style of graphics that uniquely identifies that person?

I've often heard of many forms of art the importance of creating a style, how does this apply to graphic design?

Comment: --Creativity.--

Comment: @poepje and talent. ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this applies more for designer-illustrators. As the other poster wrote, usually it's more about communicating the personality of the client's brand than your own style. That said, many designers choose to focus on specific industries, which makes sense since each industry has its own aesthetics and fashions.

However, if you're a designer-illustrator, then people will likely be coming to you because they like your particular style of illustration, which should be complimented by your design. This is when you're most likely to see a designer's portfolio contain projects all sharing a similar signature style.

There are also some well-known non-illustrator designers who are very highly sought because of their particular style of design. But very few designers ever reach that level (where they'll be requested by clients by name). So for most, it's more important to be flexible and versatile. A consistent level of quality is usually more important than a consistent style for designers.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to develop your own style, you should have a thorough understanding of the basics first. Know what works and why. Play around with different mediums and different styles. Learn the conventions of your favorite style and master them. Then start breaking rules, though always with a purpose. As you gain mastery over your favorite style, your work will begin to reflect your unique approach and artistic voice. At that point, you can even make intentional artistic signatures in your designs. The sum of all those things will be your unique design style.

Answer (score 6):

While this is not always true, graphic design often involves expressing the style and message of a website or cause rather than your own ideas. Where painters may use their work most often to express their own ideas, graphic design often involves expressing particular work. In other words, the style of graphics is usually determined primarily by the purpose of the design.